# Identifying the screen space of a particular screen on a multi screen setup on Linux

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop, xrandr

Say for example that you have three 1920x1200 screens, giving you a virtual desktop of 5760×1200. I want to be able to identify which screen space each monitor occupies in the virtual desktop. That is monitor 1: x:0-1919, y:0-1199, 2: x:1920-... etc. I need a general method since I don't know how many monitors are plugged in or how they are configured (e.g 3 5760×1200 or 1200x5760 or something else). Is this possible using standard programs on Linux?

Appreciate all help and suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that xrandr does already provide this information by default on the line for each ouput (HMDI1, DP1 etc), which I had missed :)

Answer (score -1):

yes, standard tool is 'xrandr' and for exist some GUI tools for various DM

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.